# How to add the adjacentHTML text only once onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, validation, woocommerce

I am trying to validate my woocommerce chekout form on the frontend only with javascript. The valdation executes correctly but the problem is that the function gets called everytime I remove the focus from the input field (I have used onblur event).
The div gets created multiple times. I want to have it displayed only one time else it should be removed. Can anyone suggest a solution??
Attaching the code and SS below.

```
 <h3>my custom heading</h3>
 <p class="form-row form-row validate-required">
     <input type="billing_first_name">... </p>
 <p class="sp-error-notice" id="sp_billing_first_name_field"> </p>
```

```
function myFunction() { 
  // for name
let n = document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value;
 
// let name_text;
  if ( n.length < 3 || n == '' ) {
    var n1 = document.getElementById('billing_first_name'); 
    n1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p class="sp-error-notice" id="sp_billing_first_name_field">This is a test.</p>');     
  }

  else {
     var n1 = document.getElementById("sp_billing_first_name_field");
         n1.remove(); 
       }
}
```

[The P tag gets created multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4GRW.png)

Comment: can you put your html part as well

Comment: It is created using a php loop. But the fields are like this..
<h3>my custom heading</h3>
<p class="form-row form-row validate-required">
  <input type="billing_first_name">...
</p>
<p class="sp-error-notice" id="sp_billing_first_name_field"> </p>

Comment: you must be saying like - <input type="text" id="billing_first_name">

Comment: yes it is like that

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the existence of the p tag before adding it

```
    if(!document.getElementById("sp_billing_first_name_field")){  
         n1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p class="sp-error-notice" id="sp_billing_first_name_field"></p>');     
    }
```

Comment: Can you share a demo of this using stack snippet. 
There was a typo as well in my code code which I just fixed

Comment: It won't work on stack snippet as the form code is in PHP at the backend and I am checking the validation at the frontend using js. I am checking the fields using their id's.

Comment: Your Solution works. But can you check how to hide/remove them when the condition is true??

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put `else`, because the element  `<p class="sp-error-notice" id="sp_billing_first_name_field">This is a test.</p>` was never created it can't `remove()` it in else condition. Also there is no need to put  `n == ''` in the condition your first condition is enough and satisfies  `n == ''`.

Here what I did is to check whether the element was created if that already exists it returns which causes repetition.

```js
function myFunction() { 
  // for name
let n = document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value;  
// let name_text;
if(document.getElementById("billing_first_name").nextSibling.nodeName == 'P'){
return
}
  if ( n.length < 3 ) {
    var n1 = document.getElementById('billing_first_name'); 
    n1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p class="sp-error-notice" id="sp_billing_first_name_field">Error.</p>');     
  }
}
myFunction()
myFunction()
myFunction()

function myFunction2() {
if(document.getElementById('sp_billing_first_name_field')){
  document.getElementById('sp_billing_first_name_field').style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="billing_first_name" onclick='myFunction2()'>
```

Comment: But how can you remove the error once the condition is true??

Comment: you can auto hide the p if error shows `<input type="text" id="billing_first_name" onclick="document.getElementById('sp_billing_first_name_field').style.display = 'none'" value='12'>`

Comment: this gives the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"

Comment: use this `<input type="text" id="billing_first_name" onclick='myFunction()'> `  `function myFunction() {
if(document.getElementById('sp_billing_first_name_field')){
  document.getElementById('sp_billing_first_name_field').style.display = 'none'
  }
}`

Comment: Okay this works. But now the issue is that when again the condition is false. it does not display the div. It keeps its style as display:none.

Comment: which div are you talking about ?

Comment: the display: none written in function2. That style doesn't change and the p tag remains hidden